# Select option from dropdown menu with VBA

Tags: vba, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape data from this website: https://portal.emsa.europa.eu/widget/web/thetis/inspections/-/publicSiteInspection_WAR_portletpublic

I need to input three values, the "Period" dates (which is ok) and select the "Flag" (in this case Portugal). This last one has proven to be a huge difficulty since typing is not an option.

```
Private Sub Run()

Dim objIE As Object
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
objIE.Visible = True

objIE.navigate ("https://portal.emsa.europa.eu/widget/web/thetis/inspections/-/publicSiteInspection_WAR_portletpublic")

Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:13"))

objIE.document.getElementById("tdate-1028-inputEl").Value = "01/01/2019"
objIE.document.getElementById("tdate-1029-inputEl").Value = "01/09/2019"
objIE.document.getElementById("checkcombo-1014-trigger-picker").Click
If objIE.document.getElementByClass("x-boundlist-item") = """Portugal""" Then objIE.document.getElementBy("x-combo-checker").Click
End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you try with `XMLHttpRequest` instead of `IE`? You could send a post http requests with appropriate parameters and parse the required result out of json response. If you still wanna stick to any browser simulator, try opting for selenium.

Comment: I have followed your suggestion but this goes deeper than my knowledge. So far I can find out how to / where to send the information. Any chance you could give me some help.

Answer (score 1):

You want a timed loop waiting for presence of element to click on as well as to click parent first. Sadly, I can't see an easy way to knock out the current explicit wait time used at beginning for page load to complete

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SelectFlag()
    Dim ie As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer, t As Date

    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5               '<==adjust time here
    Set ie = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

    With ie
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "https://portal.emsa.europa.eu/widget/web/thetis/inspections/-/publicSiteInspection_WAR_portletpublic"

        While .Busy Or .readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend

        With .document
            Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
            .querySelector("#checkcombo-1014-trigger-picker").Click
            Dim ele As Object
            t = Timer
            Do
                On Error Resume Next
                Set ele = .querySelector("[data-recordid='246']")
                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While ele Is Nothing
            If Not ele Is Nothing Then ele.Click
        End With

        Stop                                     '<==Delete me later

        '.quit
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @QHarr once again thanks for your help. It was after this post that I learned how to do POST requests. I have found a way to parse the JSON response and after that it was done! Will send you the code tomorrow. But your solution was a very good solution as well!

Comment: Yeah... I would also go POST route but thought you might want to know how to achieve your goal as stated above :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have meanwhile tried another option but still without success:

```
Private Sub Run()

Dim objIE As Object
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate ("https://portal.emsa.europa.eu/widget/web/thetis/inspections/-/publicSiteInspection_WAR_portletpublic")

    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:13"))

Dim iL As IHTMLElement
Dim e As IHTMLElementCollection

Set e = appIE.document.getElementById("checkcombo-1014-picker").getElementsByClass("x-boundlist-item")
For Each iL In e
  If iL.innerText = "Portugal" Then
  iL.Click
  End If
Next iL
End Sub
```